# Erase a vector element from list of vectors c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been searching for solution to this problem from this forum and others. The only results i found were about iterating through lists or accessing elements in lists of vectors. So i would like to access erase() function of a vector. But i need it done in a situation where vector is included in a list container. I have a sample code which should help explain.

```
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> a1 = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    vector <int> a2 = { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };
    vector <int> a3 = { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };

    list<vector<int>> listVec;

    listVec.push_back(a1);
    listVec.push_back(a2);
    listVec.push_back(a3);

    for (auto p : listVec){

        for (auto p1 : p){
            cout << p1;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }


}
```

So what would be the easiest way to erase one element lets say from vector a2 as it is included in a list. Right now i do not have even the wrong version.
The piece of code should be somewhere in the traversing loop but i could not write it.

Thank you

Comment: read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Comment: and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator

Comment: and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/begin

Comment: i know how erase() works i just can not find a way to access it when the vector i want to delete element from is included in a list of vectors.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the standard way to do it:

```
auto iter = listVec.begin();
std::advance(iter, 1); // get second element
iter->erase(iter->begin() + n); // erase nth element of second element of list
```

In your for-loop - you need to iterater over reference to elements - not over copies of elements, otherwise you remove element only from copy of vector:

```
int pos = 0;
for (auto& p : listVec){
//       ^
   if (++pos == 1)
   {
       p.erase(p.begin() + n); // erase nth element of second element of list
   }
}
```

List of references:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/begin
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

---

Bonus answer:

For your mentioned in comments question - where you have container `Document`and iterator to Document - like `Text_iterator` - the best is to follow the stl scheme - so add `erase` function to your `Document` and make this class friend of `Text_iterator`, see:

```
class Text_iterator {   // keep track of line and character position within            a line
    list<Line>::iterator ln;
    Line::iterator pos;
    friend class Document;
```

And:

```
struct Document {
    list<Line> line;            //doucument is a list of lines
    void erase(Text_iterator iter)
    {
        iter.ln->erase(iter.pos);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without advance(). Perfect would be the case where i can just enter the iterator of a proper element and have it erased. Is there such an option.

Comment: @fredric list iterator is not random access iterator, so not, it is not possible - see en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator , But you can have vector of vectors, not list of vectors...

Comment: @fredric Well, there's a proposal for [uniform container erasure](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4161.htm).  So soon, you'll be able to say `std::erase(listVec, "bad word")` or `std::erase_if(listVec, [](auto x) -> { return f(x); })` with _**any** type of container_!  Pretty neat, but we won't see that until C++17 :(

Comment: the code you posted worked and answered a question.
But the reason i was asking was because i wanted to work on earlier program i had trouble with and still i can not fix. The earlier post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572031/getting-basic-text-processor-in-c-to-compile
 states a problem with text processing program.
I can not find the way to erase a word  from that class Document using custom iterator that traverses through list of vector of char. I tried to make a function that erases one character first but got stuck

Comment: Thank you for the response to the Text_iterator problem.
i tried to define the function inside the struct and got following compile errors:
     Error 2 
     error C2232: '->Text_iterator::ln' : left operand has 'class' type, use '.' 
 
     Error 4 error C2232: '->Text_iterator::pos' : left operand has 'class'           type, use '.'
?
     Error 1 error C2819: type 'Text_iterator' does not have an                                       overloaded member 'operator ->'
Is there need to overload the access operator. Tried to get some examples and it seemed very specific. Is ther another way

Comment: @fredric No, no, you do not have to add `operator ->` - that was my bad, I was so sure this implementation so I did not tested/compiled it. See update - this time I checked it works with your example from this other question.

Answer (score 1):

The iteration

```
for (auto p : listVec){
```

makes a *copy* of each vector in the list as it iterates through.  So while you can call `p.erase` to erase an element of that vector, that will only affect the copy `p` and not the vector in the list.

If you instead do

```
for (auto &p : listVec){
```

`p` will now be a *reference* to each vector in the list.  So now if you call `p.erase`, that will affect the vector in the list.